# Gives a better option as this Intertia vue3

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

i will make that when a person click on a  tag that he go to a route

i found only this on google: `<a class="flex items-center p-4 mt-1" :href="routeName">`

But lately I have used livewire a lot and could `route()` and then with the route name just put something in e.g. `dashboard.user` or whatever. is this not possible?

Comment: Use Ziggy; https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Comment: yeah but what must i setup? in inertia docs stay: Vue.prototype.$route = route but in the app.js dont Vue.

Comment: okay works now! thx